# Phonegap 3.5 File Download / Moving not working

Tags: ios, cordova, download, fileapi

I am busy upgrading a Phonegap app from 3.3 to 3.5 everything works so far but the file download, opening isn't working

```
function downloadFile(url, filename, fail, downloadDone) {
    window.fail = fail;
    window.downloadDone = downloadDone;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function onFileSystemSuccess(
        fileSystem) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fileTransfer.download(url, window.filePath + filename, function(theFile) {
            window.downloadDone();
        }, function(error) {
            window.fail(error);
        });
    }, window.fail);
}

function setupFilePath(callBack) {
    window.callback = callBack;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function onFileSystemSuccess(
        fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("dummy.html", {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        }, function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            var sPath = fileEntry.root.replace("dummy.html", "");
            window.filePath = sPath;
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            fileEntry.remove();
            dataDir = fileSystem.root.getDirectory(sPath + 'cordapp', {
                create: true
            });
            window.filePath = sPath + 'cordapp/';
            console.log("FILE PATH IS: " + window.filePath)
            callBack()
        }, null);
    }, null);
}
```

Getting the error that the app can't create the directory what am I doing wrong? Is there also a way to not letting it backup to iCloud?